# Generic function for NA type

Tags: r

I want to make a special behavour for function when an argument `b` is NA.  I don't want to do this with `if` so I prefer generic. This is my try:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  UseMethod("foo", x)
}

foo.numeric <- function(x) {
  print("numeric")
}

foo.default <- function(x) {
  print("def")
}

foo.NA <- function(x) {
  print("na")
}
```

now when I run `foo(NA)` i want to run `foo.NA()` but `foo.default()` is executed.

Comment: That's because `NA` isn't a class. Try `class(NA)`.

Comment: any suggestions how to solve it? Is the only reason to make `foo.logical()` ?

Comment: If you did that you'd run into issues with `foo(TRUE)`, as well as `foo(c(1.0, NA))` (try `class(c(1.0, NA))` and `class(NA_real_)`). Why is it you want to avoid conditional statements? It's possible this is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) -- it may be that avoiding conditional statements is not necessarily the best way to solve whatever problem is causing your concern about using if statements.

Comment: because I just hate ifs.